# Julia: Remove or add key from GroupedDataFrame

Tags: dataframe, julia, grouping

Imagine I have a df on which I need to perform operations based on grouped columns. But I need two perform actions based on two groupings.

Having cols `A, B, C` I need to do operation `x` to df grouped by `A, B` and operation `y` to df grouped only by `B`. Do I need to group the dataframe twice?

## Case 1

```
df=DataFrame(rand(160,3), :auto)
rename!(df,[:A,:B,:Z])

@. df.B = ifelse(rand() < 0.5, 1, 2)
@. df.A = ifelse(rand() < 0.5, 1, 2)

# I group here by A and B
gd = groupby(df, [:A, :B])

#=
    My operations with df grouped by A and B.
    ... But now I need to perform only with B
=#
```

How to remove key A?

```
gd.removegroup([:A])
gd.removekey([:A])
gd.ungroup([:A])
```

## Case 2

```
df=DataFrame(rand(160,3), :auto)
rename!(df,[:A,:B,:Z])

@. df.B = ifelse(rand() < 0.5, 1, 2)
@. df.A = ifelse(rand() < 0.5, 1, 2)

# I group here by B
gd = groupby(df, [:B])

#=
    My operations with df grouped by B.
    ... But now I need to perform with B and A
=#
```

How to add key A?

```
groupby(gd, [:A]) ❌❌❌❌
gd.addkey([:A])
gd.addgroup([:A])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to group the dataframe twice?

Yes. Grouping twice is the same amount of coding as adding/removing group. Just do e.g.:

```
gd1 = groupby(df, [:A, :B])
gd2 = groupby(df, :B)
```

Since grouped data frame is a view of source `df`, if you mutate `gd1` the changes will be reflected in `gd2` automatically.

The only thing you need to keep in mind that when mutating `df` you should not mutate columns `:A` and `:B` as mutating grouping columns could invalidate groupings.

Comment: I was not saying because lines of code but in performance, removing a key for example would take less effort than creating another view.

Comment: I will wait another day to mark your answer as the accepted answer. I would like to know if there is another way. But thank you very much.

Comment: Your assumption that "removing a key for example would take less effort than creating another view" is not true with the implementation we have now. In DataFrames.jl it would take the same effort.